# Macro for counting observation across tabs in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple excel files that all contain upwards of 50 tabs, all of which in turn have as few as a couple rows with data points up to thousands of rows. Each row represents a delivery to a location, the name of which is the tab name. Now, the macro below returns the names of all the tabs in the excel file, but I'm attempting to write a macro that gives me a count of all the rows/observations from each, but I'm stuck.

```
Sub SheetNames() 
Columns(1).Insert 
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count 
    Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name 
Next i 
End Sub
```

For example, the above macro returns the names of the tabs 1 and 2 in a column like Tab 1/ Tab 2. However, if there are data in 3 rows of tab 1 and 4 rows of data in tab two, I'm having trouble knowing that without going into each tab, highlighting, and doing the subtraction. Does anyone know how I might figure this out?

Comment: Were you able to use the answer below, or do you need further help?

Comment: Thanks for this. It runs as you say and does the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with multiple sheets, you should always reference the sheet you want to use with the `Columns` and `Cells` functions. You can modify your code to the following to find the number of rows in the sheet and insert the sheet name that many times in Sheet1 column A:

```
Sub SheetNames()

Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim Sheet1LastRow   As Long
Dim i               As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Insert
Sheet1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    LastRow = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheet1LastRow + 1 & ":A" & LastRow + Sheet1LastRow) = Sheets(i).Name
    Sheet1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that your `For` loop starts on Sheet1. If you would like it to skip this sheet, just start at `i = 2`.